# Sending data from DB to web page

Tags: php, forms

In my form i enter ID of student, which is located in database. On submit I send entered ID to external script, where i search for name of student with entered ID. This works, and after i echo it's name it's correct, but I don't know how to send data back to the my web page so I could read student's name with GET from address bar. Code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","novi-studomat");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id=$_POST['id'];
$exe="SELECT * FROM student WHERE id='$id'";
$query=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$exe));
$ime=$query['name'];
```

I've tried with this:

```
header('Location:http://www.administrator.html.php?name=".$name."');
```

But it doesn't sends data to the page. This worked, but I think that there must be more elegant solution:

```
echo "<script>window.location.assign('http://www.administrator.html.php?name=".$name."'); </script>";
```

Comment: `Location:http://www.administrator.html.php?name=".$name."`. impressive

Comment: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)**

Comment: @Prisoner no need for sarcasm, I'm begginer...

Comment: There are two common ways to send data from the client to the server.  A `<form>` or ajax.

Comment: @IvanPandžić I didn't mean that to come off as sarcastic, I was just poking fun at the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
header('Location: http://www.administrator.html.php?name=' .$name);
```

Comment: Tnx for fast help, it is a small problem, but I'm begginer and searching on the net takes me a lot of time...

Comment: no problem :), note that the parameters dont need to be wrapped with quotes `"` or `'`

Answer (score 0):

it's simple. when you work on database table you should use primary id not other data. if you know primary id of a table, you can write any query in anywhere even you can store this id in session